# How to tell NLog to log exceptions?

Tags: nlog

Target:

```
<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${longdate} ${level} ${message} ${exception}" fileName="${basedir}/log.txt" archiveAboveSize="10485760" />
</targets>
```

When I call `Logger.Error("some message", e)`, where `e` is some exception object, it only logs the message, not the exception information. I need it to output exception message and stack trace. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to use `${exception:innerFormat=Message,StackTrace}`. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer).

Comment: How do you make this work with NLogViewer or Chainsaw targets? 
I want to use an UDP logger, such as Sentinel or Log2Console.

Comment: `<target name="udp" xsi:type="Chainsaw" address="udp4://localhost:7071" />`                                                     `<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="udp" />`

Answer (score 11):

I've found `${exception:format=tostring}` to be the best format for logging full details.

[NLog - How to Log Exceptions](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/How-to-log-exceptions)

Comment: For NLog >v5.0 you can use `${message:withexception=true}`, [see here](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/How-to-log-exceptions#exception-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Yep try adding

> includeSourceInfo="true"

to your target file, like;

```
 <target name="viewer"
            xsi:type="NLogViewer"
            includeSourceInfo="true"
            address="udp://127.0.0.1:9999" />
```